# Flutter | Auto Resize height of TableCells to fill parent

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to create custom Calendar Widget, so I use `Table` to show days number like this:

| MON. | TUE. | WED. | THU. | FRI. | SAT. | SUN. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| 29 | 30 | 31 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

And I want to Days Cells resize height to fill my parent but I can't doe it.

I have search but can't find any good solution, can probably use GridPane but no result..

here is my simplified code with `Table`:

```dart
Expanded(
    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Table(
            children: rows
                .asMap()
                .map((index, row) {
                    return MapEntry(
                        index,
                        TableRow(
                            children: row.children!
                                .map((widget) => TableCell(
                                    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                                    child: widget,
                                ))
                                .toList(),
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               border: Border(
                                   bottom: BorderSide(
                                       width: 1.0,
                                       color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary.withAlpha(80),
                                   )
                               )
                           ),
                         ),
                      );
                 })
                 .values
                 .toList(),
        ),
    ),
)
```

`rows` is `List<TableRow> rows = [];` who have all of my TableRows

and this is my current result:

[image: current result]

and this is wanted result:

[image]

Thanks for all,
ShayFox

Comment: Please elaborate on what do you mean by "And I want to Days Cells resize height to fill my parent". Maybe some simple drawing in draw.io or paint

Comment: @Albert221 I have edited my problem with screen of result/wanted result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the cells to **fill the whole parent** and the **parent has bounded constraints**, you can use `Row`s and `Column`s with children wrapped in `Expanded` to make them all fill the available width evenly:

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    for (var row = 0; row < 5; row++)
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++)
              Expanded(
                child: Text((row * 5 + col + 1).toString()),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

Comment: I seen this solution in a post but I don't choose it because I want to All cells have same width to make "Table" and this solution can use the container width so differents width for each container if have more children. And I find that table is more appropriate to this function because he also have border and same width for each cells.

Comment: You want the cells to have equal width? Putting them in expanded just like I proposed makes them have equal width (and height). I used `Text` for this example, but you can use your own widget there that has some border or other decorations.

Comment: I have test your solution but it doesn't work the way I want it to, I have edited my problem with my code for more details.

Comment: @ShayFox I looked at the screenshots in your question and this code does exactly what you need  I attached a screenshot

Comment: your solution seem work but I cannot add header.. because I test to add:
Column: (Row with header, Column( days children))
and that provide error

Comment: Add the `Row` with the day headers directly as the first child of a `Column` in my code - or - like you described: `Column { Row(headers), Expanded { Column(days) }  }` wrap the Column with children in `Expanded`

Comment: Throw BoxConstraints forces an infinite height. error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256478/discussion-between-albert221-and-shayfox).